# implement async/await functionality in es6

Tags: javascript

How would you implement async/await functionality if you had to? 
-   We’re talking about normal JS syntax (ES6) that does something like async/await, of course, not adding it to the syntax)

Comment: What? using *async function(){ await someotherasync();}* ...

Comment: Please be more specific

Comment: You're question is not really clear. Are you looking for Promise functionality?

Comment: I use generator functions that yield promises. Something like [bluebird's `Promise.coroutine`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html) can then be used to wrap those functions into a single `Promise`-returning function. You end up with something syntactically almost identical to `async`/`await`. My code still uses this approach since `async` is not (quite) standardized yet.

Answer (score 1):

`async`/`await` are syntactic sugar on top of [ES6 Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).
For example, a program that uses async/await like this

```
async function asyncExample () {
  const foo = await doStuff();
  return foo + 1;
}
```

is equivalent to the following program in ES6

```
function promiseExample () {
  return doStuff().then(foo => foo + 1);
}
```

Functions marked `async` just return a Promise that resolves to the return value of the function.